# Vector of pointers. BOOST serialization

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization

I want to serialize/deserialize using BOOST the values (not the pointers) of objects in the following vector:

```
std :: vector <A*> m_vector;
```

To serialize I use the following code:

```
int nItems = m_vector.size();
ar & nItems;
std::for_each(m_vector.begin(), m_vector.end(), [&ar](A* pItem) {
    ar & *pItem;
});
```

And to deserialize:

```
int nItems;
ar & nItems;
for (int i = 0; i < nItems; ++i) {
    A* pItem;
    ar & *pItem;  ///////////// Run-Time Check Failure #3
    m_vector.push_back(pItem);
}
```

But when I run the program I get the following error:

```
Run-Time Check Failure # 3 - The variable 'pItem' is Being Used without Being initialized.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You will need to allocate memory for the object pointed to by `pItem`:

```
A* pItem = new A;
ar & *pItem;
m_vector.push_back(pItem);
```

The error was because although you had a pointer, there was no object at the memory location where the pointer pointed to -- the value of the pointer was garbage (uninitialized pointer).

Don't forget to call `delete` when you no longer need the object pointed to by the pointer in the vector to preven memory leak.  Better yet, use a smart pointer (e.g. `boost::shared_ptr<>`) to ensure the memory is deallocated when no longer accessible.

Answer (score 3):

2 years later, but worth mentioning.

There's been a better solution to serialize a vector of **pointers to objects** or any other STL container (list, set etc.).
In order to serialize a vector, add:

```
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
```

and then you need to implement serialize() method and friend your class with archieve.
Everything is explained in this example (read all comments carefully, they're very important):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>


class Abc{
    // In order to make Abc serializable
    // you need to friend this lass with serialization::access
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    // and then add this method
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        // choose what class fields do you want to serialize
        ar & a;
        ar & b;
        ar & c;
    }
public:
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    // don't forget about default constructor! It's necessary for serialization!
    Abc(){};
    Abc(int a, int b, int c): a(a), b(b), c(c){};
};

class GpsPosition
{
private:
    // as mentioned above...
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & degrees;
        ar & minutes;
        ar & seconds;
        ar & wektorIntow;
    }
    int degrees;
    int minutes;
    float seconds;
public:
    std::vector<Abc*> abcVector;
    GpsPosition(){};
    GpsPosition(int d, int m, float s): degrees(d), minutes(m), seconds(s)
    {
        // adding some objects to abcVector
        abcVector.push_back(new Abc(1, 2, 3));
        abcVector.push_back(new Abc(3, 2, 3));
        abcVector.push_back(new Abc(2, 2, 3));
        abcVector.push_back(new Abc(1, 2, 3));
    }
    int getDegrees(){ return this->degrees; }
    int getMinutes(){ return this->minutes; }
    float getSeconds(){ return this->seconds; }
};

int main(){

    // And now how to use it

    // Saving to file:
    std::ofstream fileHandler("filename");
    const GpsPosition position1(35, 59, 24.567f);
    {
        boost::archive::text_oarchive boostOutputArchieve(fileHandler);
        boostOutputArchieve << position1;
    }

    // Reading from file:
    GpsPosition newPosition;
    {
        std::ifstream fileHandler;
        try{
            fileHandler.open("filenacme");
            boost::archive::text_iarchive boostInputArchieve(fileHandler);
            // read class state from archive
            boostInputArchieve >> newPosition;
            // archive and stream closed when destructors are called
            fileHandler.close();
            }
        catch (std::ifstream::failure e) {
            std::cerr << "Exception opening/reading/closing file";
        }
        catch(boost::archive::archive_exception e){
            std::cerr << "Exception opening/reading/closing file";
        }
    }

    // print to the console
    std::cout << newPosition.getMinutes() << std::endl; 
    std::cout << newPosition.abcVector[0]->a;
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

For more information, check out this tutorial:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

Comment: I suppose "wektorIntow" and "abcVector" should have the same name?

Comment: a minor nitpick, but a lot of information is misspelled in the provided code snippet...